# Is DBPedia a crowd-sourced project or an automatic KB extraction?

Tags: semantic-web, dbpedia

DBPedia has so many chapters in several languages and also has mapping-based predicates and raw infobox properties. However it's said DBPedia is a community effort for extracting structured information from wikipedia[like this](http://158.130.69.163/~zives/research/dbpedia.pdf) but many row properties are not reasonable at all, especially in localized datasets. have all properties produced by human or machine?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: I thought scope of these tags is beyond programming affairs. If it's off topic please notify me where can I ask such a question

Comment: The [help] has information regarding the types of question that are appropriate here. As a general rule, if it's not programming related, it's off-topic here; this is a site for programming and programmers tools related questions, as you can see in the guidelines at [this help center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For advice on where to ask instead, ask for guidance on [meta.se] and someone can direct you to a more appropriate site (or you could simply ask the DBPedia community at their site).

Comment: Wikipedia says "The English version of the DBpedia knowledge base describes 4.58 million things, out of which 4.22 million are classified in a consistent ontology". Crowdsource on such sizes makes me think automatic effort plus human intervention - and not all the results would be useful in a reasoner. However, "many row properties are not reasonable" requires more detail. Any example?

Comment: @Ignazio for example in a language specific page of wikpedia about an ancient reign only the year of publication of books mentioned in refrence and such information was extracted. Here's the [link](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A2%D8%A6%DB%8C%D9%86_%D9%87%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86). I queried `fa.dbpedia`

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your advice. Henceforth I will take your notes for asking new questions.

Comment: I think that's an example of incomplete extracted information rather than not reasonable information. But as suggested by @KenWhite the DBPedia community will provide better answers than me.

Comment: You might have better luck on a DBpedia forum, or on answers.semanticweb.com.  But in short, DBpedia data is automatically extracted from Wikipedia data, using mappings that sort of "crowd sourced."  DBpedia sets up the infrastructure to process WIkipedia infobox data (among other things), and users provide the details about how different infoboxes should be processed. DBpedia's website has lots more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the [DBPedia main page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/):

> DBpedia is a crowd-sourced community effort to extract structured information from Wikipedia[...]

This is done via the [*DBpedia information Extraction Framework*](https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/wiki), a software available in a dedicated [GitHub repository](https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework).